# WindowKeyPress (a.k.a. WindowKeyPressEvent and KeyPressFcn) doesn't trigger after pressing "alt-tab" and holding a key for a while

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Unfortunately I am having an issue when trying to listen to key pressing events. I have done the minimal example for you to work on, and check if you can reproduce this issue.

To reproduce it, press alt-tab twice (to focus out from the figure and than focus again), then hold a key for a while (i.e. 3 seconds), release it. Now press any letter key, you will see that it will either trigger release from the long holding key, or it won't trigger any event at all.

I think it has something to do with java mnemonic because other keys as ctrl, alt, cmd, and etc will always trigger the press event… but that is just a guess. I am using matlab at mac and the issue happens on both HG1 and HG2. Does anyone know how can avoid this problem?

**Here is the testing function:**

```
function tabPlotIssue()

figH=figure(1);

if feature('UseHG2')
  pressListener=addlistener(figH,'WindowKeyPress',...
    @keyPressFcn);                              
  releaseListener=addlistener(figH,'WindowKeyRelease',...
    @keyRelease);                            
else             
  pressListener=addlistener(figH,'WindowKeyPressEvent',...
    @keyPressFcn);
  releaseListener=addlistener(figH,'WindowKeyReleaseEvent',...
    @keyRelease);                            
end              

function keyPressFcn(a,b)
  disp('Pressed a key:')
  if feature('UseHG2')  
    mChar = b.Character;                      
  else
    mChar = b.Source.CurrentCharacter;
  end
  disp(mChar)
  % pressListener.Enabled = 'off'; % This is not needed to reproduce
  % the issue, but it is good in case you don't want to trigger
  % pressed key many times and make the visualization harder.
end

function keyRelease(a,b)
  disp('Released a key:')
  if feature('UseHG2')   
    mChar = b.Character;
  else
    mChar = b.Source.CurrentCharacter;
  end
  disp(mChar)
  % pressListener.Enabled = 'on'; % This is not needed to reproduce
  % the issue, but it is good in case you don't want to trigger
  % pressed key many times and make the visualization harder.
end

end
```

**And the output showing the issue:**

```
>> tabPlotIssue
>> Pressed a key: % Here I pressed alt-tab
>> Released a key: % Here I released alt-tab
>> Pressed a key: % Here I pressed q for a short time
q
>> Released a key: % Here I pressed w
q
>> Released a key: % and so on
q
>> Released a key:
q
>> Released a key:
q
>> Released a key:
q
>> Pressed a key: % Pressed alt
>> Released a key: % Released alt
>> Released a key: % Released any other key
>> Released a key: % and so on
>> Released a key:
```

---

Update:

I've changed the keyRelease function to as follows, but it keeps stop listening to event trigger. I've noticed that it would even stop listening to cmd+w, the figure get unresponsive to almost all triggers. I would appreciate if you can tell me this

```
function keyRelease(a,b)
  disp('Released a key:')
  if feature('UseHG2')
    mChar = b.Character;
  else
    mChar = b.Source.CurrentCharacter;
  end
  disp(mChar)
  % pressListener.Enabled = 'on'; % This is not needed to reproduce
  % the issue, but it is good in case you don't want to trigger
  % pressed key many times and make the visualization harder.
  delete(pressListener)
  delete(releaseListener) 
  if feature('UseHG2')                                                      
    pressListener=addlistener(figH,'WindowKeyPress',...           
      @keyPressFcn);                              
    releaseListener=addlistener(figH,'WindowKeyRelease',...       
      @keyRelease);                            
  else                                                                      
    pressListener=addlistener(figH,'WindowKeyPressEvent',...
      @keyPressFcn);
    releaseListener=addlistener(figH,'WindowKeyReleaseEvent',...
      @keyRelease);                            
  end                                                                       
end
```

Comment: Btw, sometimes it needs more than one alt-tab sequel.

Comment: You are aware that ALT triggers the menu, and therefore you should be careful how you use it. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @OlegKomarov well… I should be able to do alt-tab and that don't affect the behaviour of pressing and releasing events.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this is related to the alt being a key for suspending keyboard on mac when pressed 5 times. [Do](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3813671?start=0&tstart=0):

> System Preferences > Universal Access > Mouse & Trackpad (or Mouse) >
>   Mouse Keys > Off.